# regular expression that has /admin in the middle and whole string ends with specific format

Tags: nginx, regular-expressions

I am trying to write a regular expression such as it has /admin in the middle and ends with .css or .js or other formats.

`http://example.com/admin/static/style.css` (SHOULD WORK)

`http://example.com/admin/static/vendor.js` (SHOULD WORK)

`http://example.com/static/style.css` (SHOULD NOT WORK)

I am trying to use this in nginx location block. I tried this

```
location /admin/\.(css|js)${

}
```

but not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you want to use it for what? What have you tried? How did this fail?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Migrate this to StackOverflow? But in the mean time see if [this](https://regex101.com/) helps.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter: Why migrating this? Writing regexes for web servers is a sysadmin topic...

Comment: The problem in your example is missing `~` after `location`. Without tilde, it is a simple prefix match, not a regex match.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for a case insensitive match (`~*`):

```
location ~* ^/admin/.+\.(css|js)$ {
    # more configuration
}
```

Add other file types separated by `|` like `^/admin/.+\.(css|js|png|gif|jpe?g)$`.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be missing is the section between "admin" and "css/js". This could work:

```
(.*)\/admin(.*)\.(css|js)
```

I also added the `(.*)` in the beginning, meaning that in front of `/admin` there may be additional characters.